# How to upload file in dropbox in iphone?

Tags: iphone, dropbox

I have made code to upload image from document directory to Sample Album of Dropbox.
But it dosen't work as i want.

My code:

```
 -(NSString *)getDocumentPath{

NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"image1.jpg"];
NSLog(@"path:%@",path);
return path;
}


-(IBAction)uplaodingPhotos:(id)sender
{
  NSString *path = [self getDocumentPath];
    [[self restClient] uploadFile:@"splash.jpg" toPath:@"/Photos/Sample Album"
                withParentRev:nil fromPath:path];
```

}

In this code i want to add image image1 from document directory to Sample Album in Dropbox.
But it dosen't copy image.Now what i have to do?

Please Help.
Thank in advance.

Comment: Dropbox is dead, use Google Drive :)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make sure you are connected with dropbox session and your rest client is not nill.

For more info plz check the URL: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/start/authentication#ios